# Solving a Regex for a number range

Tags: regex

I am in need of a regfex for a validation framework which accepts regex formats for validation. 
I cannot use arithmetic and comparative operators. I have come up with a solution but It is not working as expected. 
I want to know what’s wrong with the regex which I came up with and how to sort it out right

Regex for any number from `10429` to `40999`

My solution:

```
^1042[9-9]|104[3-9][0-9]|10[5-9][0-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[2-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|40[0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

But this one is not working.

Comment: `1024[9-9]` could be just `10429`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Try this**

```
^(10429|104[3-9][0-9]|10[5-9][0-9]{2}|1[1-9][0-9]{3}|[23][0-9]{4}|40[0-9]{3})$
```

For generating pattern number Ranges visit [here](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range).

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Confirmed working in python by brute force: `r = re.compile(r'^(10429|104[3-9][0-9]|10[5-9][0-9]{2}|1[1-9][0-9]{3}|[23][0-9]{4}|40[0-9]{3})$')`
`assert all(r.match(str(n)) if n>=10429 and n<=40999 else True for n in range(100000))`

Comment: @om39a: Thank you! Go also check www.regexbuddy.com. This is the most Robust tool for learning, testing and creating Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 4):

1. `1[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` - too many digits.
2. `^1|2|3` actually means `(?:^1)|2|3` - you need `^(?:10429|...|40[0-9][0-9][0-9])$`.

Comment: @om39a: `...` was laziness, not a suggestion - the main point is using `^(?:` `)$` around your pattern. Either way, Cylian gave an automated tool, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

`10429|104[3-9][0-9]|10[5-9][0-9]{2}|1[1-9][0-9]{3}|[23][0-9]{4}|40[0-9]{3}` should do the trick.

Although why you would need this is beyond me...

Answer (score 0):

try this `^(10429|104[3-9]\d|10[5-9]\d{2}|1[1-9]\d{3}|[2-3]\d{4}|40\d{3})$`

Comment: This wont work. This will fail it i give input something like this  10429999999999999999

Comment: this is same as Cylian's one instead create myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing some very long regexes here. This task can be solved without a lot of redundancy in your pattern. If you don't have anything other than regex to work with, here's the pattern you want:

```
^(([123][1-9]|[234]0)[0-9]{3}|10([5-9][0-9]{2}|4([3-9][0-9]|29)))$
```

Here it is expanded to show you what it means:

```
 ^                      #The beginning of the line. This ensures 10429 passes, but 9999910429 doesn't.
 (                      
   ([123][1-9]|[234]0)  #This lets the first two digits be anything from 11-40. We'll deal with 10xxx later on.
   [0-9]{3}             #If the first two digits are 11-40, then the last three can be anything from 000-999. 
 |                      
   10                   #Okay, we've covered 11000-40999. Now for 10429-10999.
   (
     [5-9][0-9]{2}      #Now we've covered 10500-10999; on to the 104xx range.
   |
     4                  
     (
        [3-9][0-9]      #Covers 10430-10499.
     |
        29              #Finally, the special case of 10429.
     )
   )                  
 )
 $                      #The end of the line. This ensures 10429 passes, but 104299999 doesn't.
```

If the numbers aren't the entire input, but rather embedded in a string (e.g. you want to get all the numbers 
from the string "blah blah 11000 foo 39256 bar 22222", replace both `^` and `$` with `\b`.

See it working on Regexr: http://regexr.com?312p0

Answer (score 0):

try this - \b(10429|104[3-9][0-9]|10[5-9][0-9]{2}|1[1-9][0-9]{3}|[23][0-9]{4}|40[0-9]{3})\b